# Find Non-Empty Field Values Using Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

Under EJB I am using criteria. In that i need to fetch non empty field values from database.

For Example

```
Field name : subject
(i)  value 1    : "ABC"
(ii) value 2    : ""
```

Here I need to fetch only "ABC" alone. How to do this one using hibernate criteria.

Please suggest your solution.. Thanks in advance

Comment: As you must be using some pojo to map the table can you please suggest why you need to do it this way?

Comment: That field can accept null value. But the problem is if I search using that field name("subject") means it fetches null record also. I need to avoid in this record when that field value is empty.

Comment: So you actually do not need that record to be returned if the field value is null or empty. Is it right?

Comment: yes. But it should be in database. If empty search means it should return.

Comment: Did this work for you Sangeetha?

Answer (score 1):

First of all create session object then use the below code

```cs
 Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(TableName.class);
  crit.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("subject"));
  List<Object[]> objectList =  crit.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes as Ritika suggested you can use Restrictions as follows:

crit.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("subject"))